# relations between non-negativity of multivariate polynomials and SOS over gradient ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, computer-algebra, global-optimization

We know there is a necessary condition for the non-negativity of multivariate polynomials in the paper "Sum of Squares Decompositions of Polynomials over their Gradient Ideals with Rational Coefficients" by V. Magron, M. Safey El Din, and T.-H. Vu.

That is if $f$ is a non-negative multivariate polynomial with rational coefficients, then $f$ is a sum of squares over the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/I_{grad}(f)$ where $I_{grad}(f)$ is the ideal generated by all the partial derivatives of $f$. But to prove the converse, we need an assumption that f attain its infimum, so the extreme will be on the gradient variety.

So my question is do we really need the assumption that $f$ attain its infimum? i.e. is there any counter-example that $f$ is a sum of squares over the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/I_{grad}(f)$ but not non-negative, i.e. $f(s_1,\cdots, s_n) <0$ for some $(s_1,\cdots, s_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the answer is no. For exmaple $f(x,y)=x^4-y^4$ which is not non-negative but f is a sum of squares modulo the gradient ideal, in fact $f=x^4+y^4+\frac{1}{2}y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^4+y^4$ mod $I_{grad}(f)$.